# Linq get max() Grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I have this SQL query:

```
declare @p_Date datetime 
set @p_Date = '01/01/2015'

select * 
from inv_hist
where Secuencia in (
    select max(Secuencia)
        from inv_hist
        where DatFechaDocumento <= @p_Date
            group by Bodega,NumIdConcepto
    )
```

How can I write this query in LINQ?

EDIT: I was figthing with this all day. I'm not an expert on linq and other similar questions doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from x in invHistory
                    join y in
                            (
                                from z in invHistory
                                where z.PDate == "01/01/2015"
                                group z by new { z.Bodega, z.NumIDConcepto } into g
                                select new
                                       {
                                           NewSecuencia = g.Max(s => s.Secuencia) 
                                       }
                            ) 
                            on x.Secuencia equals y.NewSecuencia
                    select x;
```

If you want *implicit style* this is how you do it:

```
  var query2 = from x in invHistory
               from y in
                         (
                             from z in invHistory
                             where z.PDate == "01/01/2015"
                             group z by new { z.Bodega, z.NumIDConcepto } into g
                             select new
                             {
                                 NewSecuencia = g.Max(s => s.Secuencia)
                             }
                         )
               where 
                    x.Secuencia == y.NewSecuencia
               select x;
```

> Please note that the implicit style join syntax (ANSI-89) is not a standard and is deprecated from SQL Server 2005.

Comment: It works perfect, it is posible to express this query using implicit syntax? Thats why i need some other Dynamic filters.