# LINQ return the rows where column1ID = MAX column1ID grouped by column2ID

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm a total newbie to `C# MVC` and `LINQ`.

I have a table containing a complex primary key, made up of an `InvestigationActionID` and a `DocketID` and a bunch of data relevant to the row that I need to get out and put into my `view`. Given that a `Docket` can have many `InvestigationActions` I want to output a summary page with just the most recent `InvestigationAction` details per 'Docket'.

In pure `MS SQL` I can achieve this very easily as per the below:

```
SELECT a.DocketID, a.InvestigationActionID, a.ActionDate, a.PostDate, a.ActionType, a.InvestigationStatus 
    from [dbo].[InvestigationAction] a inner join
    (SELECT [DocketID], Max([InvestigationActionID]) as MaxIAID
         FROM [dbo].[InvestigationAction]
              group by DocketID) b
         on a.DocketID = b.DocketID and a.InvestigationActionID = b.MaxIAID
```

I have tried a few suggestions of how to achieve something similar but I'm just not getting what I want the best I've done so far is to get one row where `DocketID` and `InvestigationActionID` are both 1, but that really doesn't help me.

The below is an example of a query I tried that returned the wrong data:

```
from t in InvestigationActions
where !(from tt in InvestigationActions
        where tt.DocketID == t.DocketID &&
            tt.InvestigationActionID > t.InvestigationActionID
        select tt
        ).Any()
select t
```

All assistance is appreciated.

Comment: `I have tried a few suggestions of how to achieve something similar but I'm just not getting what I want` -> show us what you've tried, and if possible tell us how it didn't meet expectations.

Comment: as an example I have tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977255/linq-get-max-grouping) but with the changes I've made to try and make it fit my model, I just get one row with `DocketID = 1` and `InvestigationActionID = 1`, this row isn't even the row with the highest 'InvestigationActionID` for the `DocketID`, but the row did include all the columns I needed, just not the right results.

`from t in InvestigationActions
where !(from tt in InvestigationActions
  where tt.DocketID == t.DocketID &&
   tt.InvestigationActionID > t.InvestigationActionID
  select tt
  ).Any()
select t`

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are using entity framework:

```
var db = new YourContext();

var queryMax = from b in db.InvestigationActions
               group b by b.DocketId into g
               select new { 
                    DocketId = g.Key, 
                    MaxIAID = g.Max(c=>c.InvestigationActionID) 
               };

var query = from i in db.InvestigationActions
            join m in queryMax on i.DocketID equals m.DocketID 
            and  i.InvestigationActionID equals b.MaxIAID
            select i;
```

Or if not:

```
var queryMax = from b in InvestigationActionsList
               group b by b.DocketId into g
               select new { 
                    DocketId = g.Key, 
                    MaxIAID = g.Max(c=>c.InvestigationActionID) 
               };

var query = from i in InvestigationActionsList
            join m in queryMax on i.DocketID equals m.DocketID 
            and  i.InvestigationActionID equals b.MaxIAID
            select i; //change this if you want, see comments below
```

if you want only the fields that you listed on your select, change the last line:

```
select i;
```

to:

```
select new { i.DocketID, i.InvestigationActionID, i.ActionDate, i.PostDate, i.ActionType, i.InvestigationStatus };
```

or:

```
select new InvestigationAction() { DocketId = i.DocketId, ... other fields that you may want };
```

Comment: that has solved it!!! +1

minor edit to the code that tried in LINQpad which sorted it out. Many thanks!!!
`var queryMax = from b in InvestigationActions
               group b by b.DocketID into g
               select new { 
                    DocketId = g.Key, 
                    MaxIAID = g.Max(c=>c.InvestigationActionID) 
               };

var query = from i in InvestigationActions
            from m in queryMax 
   where i.DocketID == m.DocketId 
            where i.InvestigationActionID == m.MaxIAID
            select i;`